# fail to deploy node to heroku due to bcrypt

Tags: node.js, heroku

A few days ago, I built a backend app using node.js and I successfully deploy it to heroku. Today I build the exactly same thing but I fail to deploy it and I do not know how to fix this 
Here are the error

```
remote:        > bcrypt@1.0.3 install /tmp/build_e9e73855f7912a4acc55f89ae92f6e41/node_modules/bcrypt
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote:        sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 126
remote:        npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 126
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.55byY/_logs/2018-04-06T19_42_56_019Z-debug.log
```

I really need to deploy this server today. Could you please show me how to fix this error? I have tried some solutions that I found but nothing worked. I even tried to install python and set path in environment.

Comment: What version of node?

Comment: my node version is v8.11.1 and npm is 5.7.1

Comment: downgrading to 7.x could work if you need fast solution

Comment: How can I downgrading my node version

Comment: @coinhndp You can specify the version of node in your package.json https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

Comment: It is still failed when I set it to version 7.7.3

Comment: Thank you so much. I have found solution. Just use bcryptjs  instead of bcrypt

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install --save bcrypt-nodejs && npm uninstall --save bcrypt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save bcryptjs && npm uninstall --save bcrypt
```

bcrypt-nodejs is no longer actively maintained. thats why bcryptjs is alternate for it!